# What combination of MPMediaItem metadata could be considered to be a GUID?

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem

I do not see any metadata on MPMediaItem that could be considered to be a globally unique identifier (in other words, the same piece of media would have the same, unique combination of values across multiple devices and user accounts). Is there a recommended metadatum that could be used in this way (or a compound set of metadata)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `MPMediaItem`s and some other `MediaPlayer.framework` classes have a unique identifier called a persistent ID. It is a `uint64_t` wrapped in an `NSNumber`. Here are the persistent IDs you can retrieve from an `MPMediaItem` using `valueForProperty:`

```
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyPersistentID;            // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumPersistentID;       // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyArtistPersistentID;      // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumArtistPersistentID; // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyGenrePersistentID;       // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyComposerPersistentID;    // filterable
NSString *const MPMediaItemPropertyPodcastPersistentID;     // filterable
```

Comment: Thank you. Are these persistent ID's consistent across multiple devices and Apple ID's? Are there any third-party services that can map one of Apple's persistent ID's to other metadata (e.g. artist, song, album, etc)?

Comment: No, they are specific to a device. Currently, there is no Apple-recommended way to do that. I suggest you mash up the Song Title, Artist and Release Date to create a GUID, as these are the most unique metadata of a song. Also, explore the Gracenote API. It is a music recognition service that sends back correct metadata.